# Javascript Files that enable sending and receiving json data in phonegap

Tags: javascript, json, cordova, blackberry-webworks

Which javascript files must be available either in client-side or server-side for you to be able to send and receive json data in your BlackBerry phonegap application.

I see this often omitted in all the solutions to json-related questions that have been posted.

I am completely new to phonegap and jQuery and so I need help also I am trying to send form details (like firstName and lastName) to a php file on the server-side.

So that the data would be processed by the php and the record would be stored on my database.

Can some one work me through how to send the data using json?

Answer (score 0):

You can get detail on Json integration in phonegap from this [blog](http://catchmayuri.blogspot.in/2012/01/working-with-json-phonegap-application.html).

this blog will explain through a simple example how you can use JSON to ease the client-server data transmission.

Don't bother about server site, server team (PHP/Java) will take care of it.
In phonegap app every logic is buid in javascript, so in your case if you want to send some information to server, you need to create json object and append it to `$.ajax` function and same function to receive the response from server:

```
$.ajax({  
   url:'stringURL',  
   beforeSend: function(x) {      
     x.setRequestHeader('Authorization','username/pwd');  
   },  
   dataType:"json",  
   contentType:'application/json',  
   timeout:10000,  
   type:'POST', 
   data : {
     //append json data here if you want to send some data to server
   }, 
   success:function(data) {  
     alert(data); // here you will get json data on success, parse it like key-value mechanism in js 
   },  
   error:function(XMLHttpRequest,textStatus, errorThrown) {     
     alert("Error status :"+textStatus);  
     alert("Error type :"+errorThrown);  
     alert("Error message :"+XMLHttpRequest.responseXML);  
   }
});
```

Please have a look at this [blog](http://phpmaster.com/writing-a-restful-web-service-with-slim/) to write php-web service or share with you server team.

Comment: Should the dataType not be "json"? How does the $.ajax() function receive data from the server?

Comment: Please how do I setup a web service?

Comment: It's PHP-APACHE server. I actually have a web application on an online server. I am trying to send json data to a php file on the server so it can get the data and use it to query the database on the server. Then the php page can send back a response to the phone? How do i do this. Explain in detail as if because I am a novice.

Comment: Does this mean I will be able to send json data to my php files once they set up a restful web service? I read somewhere that making Ajax calls cross-domain will break the sandbox model of Javascript? Can you explain in detail for me how a restful web service counters that?

Comment: I contacted the company which hosted my php server. They claim they do not know about REST and how to set up a web service for my mobile application. Are they not the ones to create the web service?

Comment: if they dont know then they have to learn it share my link bro, if you want to access db and want to do all DML operation, you will need a web service (it might be simple php program).